# How to solve for composition function?

Tags: equation-solving, functions

If $ f(x)=x+6, h(x) = 6x-2$ and $g\circ f = h$, how can I solve for $g(x)$? I know how to do it on paper, but I wonder if Mathematica can do it in a general way. This doesn't work:

```
f[x_] := x + 6;
h[x_] := 6 x - 2;
Solve[ (g @* f )[x] == h[x], g]
```

Comment: Unfortunately I think mathematica can't solve for functions per se...however, you could possibly try to use `InverseFunction` in some way to express $h \circ f^{-1}$, *or* do something clever by somehow turning this into a differential equation for `g`. That would be cool. Of course both of these approaches have restrictions, and I'd be happy to see a more general approach.

Comment: Formally: `Composition[Function[x, 6 x - 2], InverseFunction[Function[x, x + 6]]][x]`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Solve` basically works on the level of symbolic algebra, so break down the composition in terms of substitution:

```
f[x_] := x + 6;
h[x_] := 6 x - 2;

g[u_] = g[u] /. First@Solve[{g[u] == h[x], u == f[x]}, g[u], {x}]
(*  2 (-19 + 3 u)  *)

ClearAll[g];
g[f[x]] == h[x] // Simplify
(*  True  *)
```

Restriction: As @thorimur's comment implies, `f` must be invertible; further Mathematica has to be able to somehow solve for the inverse. Note in the above `Solve` command, `f` does not actually appear itself, just its value, so that solving for the inverse is merely a simple algebra problem.  Yet, Mathematica can use `InverseFunction`:

```
Clear[f, g]

g[u_] = g[u] /. First@Solve[{g[u] == h[x], u == f[x]}, g[u], {x}]
```

> Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.

[image]